# Charge second page in dart web without frameworks

Tags: html, dart, web, dart-html

My **index.html** with linked **main.dart** file

```
<head>
   <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"/>
</head>

<body>  
   <a href="/secondpage.html"/>
</body>
```

My **secondpage.html** with linked **second.dart** file

```
<head>
   <script type="application/dart" src="second.dart"/>
</head>

<body>  
   <button id="buttonTest">Test</button>
</body>
```

I can't use **main** method in **second.dart** file... So how I can access/initialize a

```
ButtonElement test = querySelector ("#buttonTest");
test.onClick.listen((e)=>print("clicked"));
```

No AngularDart, only dart without any framework

Comment: Which is your dart version?

Comment: Dart 2, last dev version

Comment: The script type `application/dart` works only in chromium which is deprecated in Dart2

Comment: Ok, it's not the problem. I only copy and paste from dart website. My question is different